# How to sum variabiles in Jinja template

Tags: django, jinja2

I want to print sum of two values in jinja in the last `table data` tag

```
{% for product in invoice.all %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
                <td>{{product.unit_price}}</td>
                <td>{{product.quantity + product.unit_price}}</td>
            </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

What is the proper way of doing this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can add by
{{ product.quantity|add:product_unit_price }}

Comment: Happy to help. :)